# Will this make my grammar ambigious?

Tags: context-free-grammar

ok lets say i have the following grammar

```
<Exp> ->  <Term>
<EXp>  -> <Term> {<AddOp> <Exp>}  
<Term> -> <Factor> {<MultOp> <Term>}
<Factor> -> <id> |  <no> | ( <Exp> )
```

The thing inside {} is optional. so i can technically just have exp->term or term->Factor. Now the following derivation is possible for lets say number 10. exp->term->factor->no->10.. can i just add no to exp?

```
<Exp> ->  <Term>|<no>
```

or will this make the grammar ambiguous or any other problems? Thanks.

P.s Addop and MultOp are just + and *

Answer (score 0):

Your initial grammar is already ambiguous: `<Exp>` derives `<Term>` in two different ways, via production 1 and via production 2. Production 1 doesn't add anything to the grammar, so you can just remove it, and you'll get an unambiguous grammar for the same language.

But then, if you add the production `<Exp> -> <no>`, you'll get an ambiguous grammar again, because `<Exp>` will derive `<no>` in two different ways. The first way you've already shown, and the second way is a trivial application of the new production.